# php smtp ssl html mail not working

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

Can someone please advise I already looked online and tried everything I can think of my I am only getting plain text email...

Email part is working is only the HTML stuff not I get the $body (message) in raw code rather than html format.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Home Calendar <calendar@home>";
 $to = "Me Yahoo <me@yahoo.co.uk>, Me Gmail <me@gmail.com>";
 $subject = "TESTING PHP EMAIL";
 $body = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ricardo</td>
            <td>Wagemaker</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
";

 $host = "ssl://mail.domain.co.uk";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "name@domain.co.uk";
 $password = "password";

$headers = array (
        "MIME-Version: 1.0",
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject
        );

 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body, $from, $subject);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("\n\n<p>Message successfully sent!</p>\n\n");
  }
 ?>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well no help but I finally figured it out, it was all about the new line "rn" missing from my headers..

Here is the modification that worked.

```
$headers = array (
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0rn',
    'Content-Type' => "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1rn",
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
 );
```